# python: Convert bytearray to ctypes Struct

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I have an 'n' Byte bytearray. This is same as one of the defined ctypes.Sturcture. I want to typecast this bytearray to this sturcture. so that I can access each of this member. How can I do that?

```
class ABC(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_uint), ("b", c_ushort), ("c", c_ushort)]

class DEF(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("abc", ABC), ("i", I)]

b = bytearray(b'\x88\x08\xc0\xf9\x02\x85\x10\x00\xcc')

s = DEF()
print(s.abc.a)
```

How do I get the the correct value of the above `print` statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`from_buffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_buffer) on the desired type (rather than the object instance):

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_uint, c_ushort, c_uint8


class ABC(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("a", c_uint), ("b", c_ushort), ("c", c_ushort)]


class DEF(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("abc", ABC), ("i", c_uint8)]


def main():
    b = bytearray(b'\x88\x08\xc0\xf9\x02\x85\x10\x00\xcc')

    # check if bytearray can be applied to structure.
    if len(b) < ctypes.sizeof(DEF):
        print("error: bytearray is too short for DEF.")
        return

    s = DEF.from_buffer(b)
    print("abc.a: {:#x}".format(s.abc.a))
    print("abc.b: {:#x}".format(s.abc.b))
    print("abc.c: {:#x}".format(s.abc.c))
    print("i: {:#x}".format(s.i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that the structure must be packed accordingly, thus I used a `_pack_ = 1` so the expected size of `DEF` structure is 9 bytes (4 + 2 + 2 + 1) rather than 12.
I also used `c_uint8` for the `DEF.i` field as this is probably what you meant (`I`, in your example, is not a type).

Output:

```
abc.a: 0xf9c00888
abc.b: 0x8502
abc.c: 0x10
i: 0xcc
```

If you want the value in big endian (rather than the default little endian), change the endianness of the structure by using [`ctypes.BigEndianStructure`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.BigEndianStructure).

Comment: You could also add an explanation of the `alignment` function, the reason for the native aligned access to data types, and how that relates to the padding bytes added to `DEF` for the case of default packing. This way the requirement to use `_pack_ = 1` will be more clearly understood.