# How to use python ctypes with a bytearray?

Tags: python, ctypes

How do I use python's `ctypes` library to read/write from a bytearray?

I can create a structure like below:

```
from ctypes import *

class Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('b0', c_byte),
        ('b1', c_byte),
        ('s0', c_short),
        ('l0', c_long),
    ]

f = Foo(1, 0x42, 0xF00F, 0x12345678)
```

But `dir(Foo)` does not show any way to create a Foo from a bytearray and `dir(f)` doesn't show any way to convert a Foo into a bytearray or write to a bytearray. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Note: this combines [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194209/python-convert-bytearray-to-ctypes-struct/29194835) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926139/convert-ctypes-struct-to-bytearray-in-python) answers

Say we have the following type

```
from ctypes import *

class Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('b0', c_byte),
        ('b1', c_byte),
        ('s0', c_short),
        ('l0', c_long),
    ]

f = Foo(1, 0x42, 0xF00F, 0x12345678)
```

You can get the value as bytes simply by using `bytearray`:

```
f_bytearray = bytearray(f)
```

Similarly, if you want to mutate a bytearray you can do so:

```
b = bytearray(32)
b[10:10+sizeof(f)] = f
```

If you want to convert a bytearray into a structure you can do so using `from_buffer`

> Note: for some reason in python3, `from_buffer` is not included in `dir(Foo)`.

```
# shares the buffer: mutating f will mutate f_bytearray
f = Foo.from_buffer(f_bytearray)
# OR copies the data to a new buffer
f = Foo.from_buffer_copy(f_bytearray)
```

Bonus: you can get offset information from (for example) `Foo.l0.offset`. With this you should be able to read/write a struct to a bytearray no problem :D

Comment: Note that the instance returned by `.from_buffer()` *shares* the the bytearray buffer. 
 If that is not desired, use `.from_buffer_copy()`.

Comment: Oh, very interesting! Adding that